# Get index number of static text with a certain value (AppleScript)

Tags: user-interface, text, static, applescript

Fairly new to AS, but I haven't come across a similar question. I am using AppleScript to get information from the UI of an app window. The window has a static text x with value "Name", and I want to get the value of the next static text, which would be static text x + 1 ("John Smith"). The value of x differs with each case, however, so I cannot simply refer to static text 9 as it can be static text 47 next time.

My solution now is to get the value of every static text available in the window and add it to a list. Then I find the first item with value "Name", and refer to that item + 1 to get the actual name I want. However, as the window can contain quite a lot of static texts, this method takes some unnecessary time.

```
set MyList to {}
tell application "System Events" to tell process "cBK" to set y to count static text of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1
repeat with x from 1 to y
tell application "System Events" to tell process "cBK" to set end of MyList to value of static text x of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1
end repeat
on findFirst(lst, val)
local lst, val, i
try
    if lst's class is not list then error "not a list." number -1704
    if {val} is not in lst then return 0
    script k
        property l : lst
    end script
    repeat with i from 1 to count of k's l
        if k's l's item i is val then return i
    end repeat
on error eMsg number eNum
    error "Can't findFirst: " & eMsg number eNum
end try
end findFirst
set Name to item (findFirst(MyList, "Name") + 1) of MyList
```

Is there a simple way to get x of static text x with a certain value, so I can get value of static text x + 1?

Answer (score 2):

You can get, from your front window, all static text values in a list with single instruction. Then search in that list and when found, just get next item. Script bellow gives an example:

```
set myTarget to "Name"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "cBK" to set myValues to value of every static text of front window
    repeat with i from 1 to count of myValues
        if item i of myValues is myTarget then exit repeat
    end repeat
    if i < (count of myValues) then
        set myNext to item (i + 1) of myValues
    else
        set myNext to "" -- not found
    end if
end tell
```

The last test checks that value has been found in a static text or return "" if not.